# SQL - data containing a list of things?

Tags: mysql, sql, list, database-design

I'm working on a Database of collectible cards. So far I'm walking in the dark, but I think I somehow manage it. What I stumbled upon is a huge problem, I can't seem to find a solution on the internet:

There is a table of different cards, which has id of card (Primary Key), and columns containing info of cards.
There is also a table of users, and those users can have cards in their collection.

Now question: how to build a table/tables that shows that a certain user has some cards in certain numbers, which data are in cards table.

Link to DB image below:

http://imageshack.com/a/img856/2404/ogu0.png

The same problem I have with decks: There is an owner of a deck, and that deck have many cards in different numbers.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Add a "cardsdecks" table with id_card, id_deck, quantity columns.  You could do the same thing for collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table called user_card_relations( For example ) with the following fields

- relation_id( Primary Key).
- card_id( Foreign key to cards table).
- user_id( Foreign key to user table ).

Inorder to list the details you can use SQL JOIN commands.